# Python comprehension for dictionary with String key and List values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am looking for comprehension to read a csv and create a dictionary where key is string and value is list

the csv looks like

```
fruit,Apple
vegetable,Onion
fruit,Banana
fruit,Mango
vegetable,Potato
```

my output should be like

```
{'fruit':['Apple','Banana','Mango'],'vegetable':['Onion','Potato']}
```

I am looking for dictionary comprehension to do that , I tried like

```
def readCsv(filename):
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
        dicttest={row[1]:[].append(row[2]) for row in readCSV}
        return dicttest
```

Comment: Please take note that you're delimiter does not match your example. Your example data has commas, but you up in your CSV reader using tabs.  Additionally note that your example file has two columns which would be indexed by 0 and 1. In your code you are a indexing by 1 and 2.

Comment: Also note in @elomat's valid answer below simple for loop is used. That is the most obvious approach here. A dictionary comprehension would not be appropriate. (It could be made to work with sorting the entire input and using `itertools.groupby` with a lambda function, but that is less memory efficient and likely less performant than the posted solution.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the performance part, I have omitted the dictionary comprehension idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
import csv
def readCsv(filename):
    d = {}
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')

        for row in readCSV:
            d.setdefault(row[0], []).append(row[1])
    return d

print(readCsv('test.csv'))
```

Comment: It is important to note that `r = row[0].split(',')` is unnecessary if the OP would specify the correct delimiter when creating the reader. It's possible that the OP showed comma separated in his example for display purposes but that his real data actually uses tabs. If so the OP should skip that line.